# Send XML to php script from flash AS2

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have to send some specific xml to a php script (from flash AS2) that then sends out sms message based on the xml. I have been given the xml by the sms sender and have tested it via their live demo and that works fine. The problem I am having is getting flash to send this XML.

The sms sender states that it needs to recieve the xml in the following format: The XML Document should be posted uriencoded, with a UTF‐8 character set as paramaeter 'xml'

Here is the code I have so far, I think something is missing maybe. I have tried running the swf in a browser rather than in the flash testing environment

```
    var my_xml:XML = new XML('<xml></xml>');

my_xml.contentType = "text/xml";



send_btn.onRelease = function () {
   my_xml.send("http://address-to-send-to.com" , "_blank");

   };
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my_xml.sendAndLoad instead of my_xml.send that should return the xml back to your object.

Cheers